# R : add a column with missing values to a dataframe

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, missing-data

I am using financial data and the row names of my main dataframe are dates.

```
   > assets[1:3,1:5]
            ALD   SFN  TCO KIM   CTX
2003-01-03 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34
2003-01-06 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34
2003-01-07 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34
```

I would like to add a column (here I want to add FOC$close to assets) from a dataframe that is of same type but some dates are missing :

```
   > FOC[1:3,1:2]
           Close Adj.Close
2003-01-03   510       510
2003-01-07   518       518
```

The missing values should just be NA's, so it would look like that :

```
   > assets[1:3,1:6]
            ALD   SFN  TCO KIM   CTX FOC
2003-01-03 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 510
2003-01-06 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 NA
2003-01-07 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 518
```

Is there a nice way to do that? I managed to do something similar with rows by doing something like

```
> rowtoadd <- list(ALD=18.1,...)
> dataframe[nrow(dataframe) + 1, names(rowtoadd)] <- rowtoadd
```

but I am not able to do this for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **merge** method.

I think you are using xts time-series objects. These handle the row names automatically. From `help(merge.xts)`, there is a keyword argument **join** that you can use to control how the merge occurs. It defaults to 'outer'. Example:

```
dat = merge(assets[1:3,], FOC[,1:2], join='left')
> dat
            ALD   SFN  TCO KIM   CTX Close Adj.Close
2003-01-03 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34   510       510
2003-01-06 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34    NA        NA
2003-01-07 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34   518       518
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP was looking for. The problem is that the row names are still ignored. (see the last comment in my answer)

Comment: I just found what I needed :                                         dat <- merge(assets,FOC,by="row.names",all.x=T)                    does the trick, I didn't know I could use all.x=T to get the NA's. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Robert Krzyzanowski Thank you -- I updated the response to make it clear that merge for xts operates on the row names (which must be dates).

Answer (score 0):

You could fill them in first and then cbind:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(list(split(rep(c(48.1, 23.98, 23.5, 23, 22.34), each = 3), rep(1:5, each = 3))))
colnames(df) <- c('ALD', 'SFN', 'TCO', 'KIM', 'CTX')
row.names(df) <- paste0('2003-01-0', c(3, 6, 7))
df <- df[order(as.POSIXct(row.names(df))), ] # This is important for cbind to work right
FOC <- data.frame(Close = c(510, 518), Adj.Close = c(510, 518))
row.names(FOC) <- paste0('2003-01-0', c(3, 7))

# Fill in NAs
FOC[setdiff(row.names(df), row.names(FOC)), ] <- NA
df <- cbind(df, FOC[order(as.POSIXct(row.names(FOC))), 1])
colnames(df)[length(df)] <- 'FOC'
```

The result:

```
            ALD   SFN  TCO KIM   CTX FOC
2003-01-03 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 510
2003-01-06 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 NA
2003-01-07 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 518
```

Sort by `as.POSIXct(row.names(..))` is important because `cbind` does not check. Without it, we would get

```
            ALD   SFN  TCO KIM   CTX FOC
2003-01-03 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 510
2003-01-06 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 518
2003-01-07 48.1 23.98 23.5  23 22.34 NA
```